# question about useEffect in react and the dom elements

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I got this function that return some array with jsx elements that will later will be displayed in DOM:

```
 function createSlides() {
    if (games.length === 0) return;
    const sliderImgs = games.map((game, i) => {
      const gameUrl = game.imgUrl;
      const gameId = game.id;
      return (
        <figure
          key={gameId}
          data-gameid={gameId}
          className="gaming__feature-img-container"
        >
          <img
            alt="game"
            src={gameUrl}
            className="gaming__feature-slider-img"
          />
        </figure>
      );
    });
    return sliderImgs;
  }
  const slides = createSlides();
```

I got this useEffect in a component:

-In slides are the slides that should be in DOM, the slides returned from the above function;

-In el2 we have just an ordinary jsx element that doesn't come from any function, it is hard coded, so it is an element that the component returns;

```
useEffect(() => {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".gaming__feature-img-container");
    const el2 = document.querySelector(".gaming__feature-section");
    console.log(slides);
    console.log(el2);
  }, []);
```

Now, if I know correctly, useEffect runs after the DOM of the component has mounted, so when I get my slides, I get an empty list. But el2 is the actual dom element, why is that? I used the slides variable in the jsx returned by the component.

Comment: `But el2 is the actual dom element, why is that?` presumably, you're returning some element from rendering that matches that selector. Can you show us the return statement of your component?

Comment: `const SomeComponent= ()=> {return   <section className="gaming__feature-section"> {slides}</section>}`

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused why you expect `el2` to not exist. You're creating a `<section>` with the class name "gaming__feature-section", and then after the render you're querying for it and finding it. Why would it *not* find it?